# Python package not seeing module in same directory

Tags: python, python-3.8

My project structure is like this:

```
Project
│   main.py
│
└───dataPacks
    │   hwPack.py
    │   swPack.py
    │   __init__.py
```

in `dataPacks/__init__.py` I'm trying to import swPack.py with the line `import swPack` for use as a Package module but it doesn't seem to see it. I am getting the error `No module named 'swPack'`

Why can't it see the module?

Comment: `Project/dataPacks` isn't in your `PYTHONPATH`, therefore you can't import those files.  You can use a relative import `from . import swPack` which means "import swPack from the same directory as this file".

Comment: Yes.. that is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the below, as dunder init is used to initialize all the other modules, so if you are in **init**.py you have to use the below code in order to import swPack.py:

```
import dataPacks.swPack
```

Answer (score -1):

```
from Project.dataPacks import swPack
```

Comment: I shared every line of code in that file, it is literally just `import swConfig`

Comment: I didn't try it as Ali's answer is shorter and works, I can't mark an answer for 3m